# I created a simple website for personal use but one of the panels moves

Tags: html, css

Okay so i have created a simple website for personal reasons and i have ran into a problem.. If you run the code below and look at the white panel at the right classed as .newsLetter and resize the screen, it moves out of place unlike the one above which i just floated right. But if i float this one to the right then it floats towards the middle of the page but works like i would like it to.. Im going to make this responsive and need to have it like the one above .newsLetter in order to do so. Do you have a fix...?? Please help! Thanks!:)

Code: 
HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   Home
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 </head>
 <body class="body">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="bg">
    <div class="mainHeader">
     <nav>
      <ul>
       <li class="last">
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#">Products</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="topArea">
     <div class="topAInfo">
      <h2>
       Here is just a simple title
      </h2>
      <p>
       This is just a little bit of dummy text. This is just a little bit of dummy text. This is just a little bit of dummy text. This is just a little bit of dummy text.
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="middleArea">
     <div class="middleAInfo">
      <h3>
       Welcome to
      </h3>
      <p>
       A dummy website!!
      </p>
     </div>
     <div class="rightInfo">
      <div class="latestNews">
       <hr>
       <h2>
        Latest News
       </h2>
       <div class="post">
        <p class="date">
         March 28, 2015
        </p>
        <p>
         New advanced update with double speed and a whole bunch of cool new st.. <a href="#">more&gt;&gt;</a>
        </p>
       </div>
       <div class="post">
        <p class="date">
         March 28, 2015
        </p>
        <p>
         New advanced update with double speed and a whole bunch of cool new st.. <a href="#">more&gt;&gt;</a>
        </p>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="newsLetter">
       <div class="newsLInfo"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: SketchFont;
  src: url(Fonts/Sketch_Block.ttf);
}
body {
  background: #ebebeb;
  width: 80%;
  height: 1300px;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
.mainHeader nav {
  width: 95%;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
  top: 60px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(90, 215, 240, 0.75), rgb(33, 171, 198));
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(90, 215, 240, 0.75), rgb(33, 171, 198));
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(90, 215, 240, 0.75), rgb(33, 171, 198));
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(90, 215, 240, 0.75), rgb(33, 171, 198));
  /* Standard syntax */
  /*margin: 100px 50px 0 150px;*/
}
.mainHeader nav ul {} .mainHeader nav ul li {
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ADADA8;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li.last {
  border-right: none;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  /*margin:10px Use to replace paddings right/left but causes hovedr errors*/
  font-family: Arial;
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li a:hover {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFA313, #FB9F0E);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#FFA313, #FB9F0E);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FFA313, #FB9F0E);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(#FFA313, #FB9F0E);
  /* Standard syntax */
}
.topArea {
  width: 95%;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
  top: 10px;
  /*margin: -50px 50px 0 150px;*/
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(90, 215, 240, 0.75), rgb(33, 171, 198));
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(90, 215, 240, 0.75), rgb(33, 171, 198));
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(90, 215, 240, 0.75), rgb(33, 171, 198));
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(90, 215, 240, 0.75), rgb(33, 171, 198));
  /* Standard syntax */
}
.topArea .topAInfo {
  margin: 20px;
  padding-top: 60px;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 50px;
  font-family: ;
}
.topArea .topAInfo h2 {
  font-family: SketchFont;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.topArea .topAInfo p {
  line-height: 25px;
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1200px;
  position: relative;
  left: 10%;
  background: linear-gradient(blue, white, white, blue);
  /* Standard syntax */
  /*background-image:url(bg2.jpg);*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.middleArea {
  background: linear-gradient(white, white, #55C4E9);
  /* Standard syntax */
  ;
  height: 600px;
  width: 95%;
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
  top: 10px;
}
.middleArea .middleAInfo {
  padding: 30px 0 0 30px;
}
.middleArea .middleAInfo p {
  color: #49CBF0;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.middleArea .latestNews {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #0099cc;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: -60px;
}
.middleArea .latestNews hr {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  color: black;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.middleArea .latestNews h2 {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  color: white;
}
.middleArea .latestNews p.date {
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
}
.middleArea .latestNews p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  width: 225px;
}
.middleArea .latestNews a {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.middleArea .rightInfo .newsLetter {
  background: white;
  width: 250px;
  height: 170px;
  position: relative;
  top: 250px;
  left: 75.6%;
}
```

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it, all i did was move the panel into the same div as the one above. DUHHHH

Answer (score 0):

fixed it

http://jsfiddle.net/74ej89of/

use `float` instead of `left`

```
.middleArea .rightInfo .newsLetter {
  background: white;
  width: 250px;
  height: 170px;
  top: 250px;
  float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to class topArea

```
.topArea{
   left:0;
}
```